# Angular v10 ngserve SSL Intermittently Failing

Tags: angular, ssl, ssl-certificate

I've got an Angular 10 project that I'm trying to debug with ngserve, and I need to use SSL both for geolocation testing and for using cookies to track user sessions.

I'm running into multiple errors where the site won't load (tested in Chrome and Edge) because of `net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200 (OK)` errors. Sometimes I can open the home page in the /src/app folder of the website, sometimes the browser tells me there's been an SSL protocol error with "vendor.js" or "main.js" or "styles.js" or any of the other .js files defined in the /src/index.html file. Without changing any files or configuration, I get different results when I reload the page - sometimes it loads just fine, sometimes it fails because of an SSL protocol error. It seems random.

And on the rare occasions that I do get the home page to load, any time I try to load a page that requires lazy-loading the mobile from another "project" in my website (outside of the /src folder), I ***always*** get the `net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200 (OK)` error.

Comment: I have same issue like that. Do you have any solution?